# Passing String array from javascript to jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I googled a lot but I can't solve my problem. I'm new on jsp, in my application in the main jsp I retrive from a table an array of strings (portfolio items) through a scriptlet in javascript. I have to POST the array to another jsp and passing as parameter into a java method to calculate some portfolio stats (historical data are stored in src directories). The code I wrote is:

```
    //obj is the array
    var obj= $('#tablePtf td:nth-child(1)').map(function(response){
        return $(this).text();
    }).get();

    //POST
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "calculatePtf.jsp",
        data: {portfolio:obj},
        success: function(){
            alert('ok');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

on the server side (caluclatePtf.jsp):

```
String[]r=request.getParameterValues("portfolio");
calculate(r);// my method
```

This causes the NullPointerException on 'r' , so I'm wrong in posting the array. The 'obj' array is not empty (tested).
I tried also dynamically writing hidden inputs setting the 'name' attribute to 'portfolio' and submitting the form but the exception persists.
Where am I wrong? Sugestions for better solution are well accepted. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved, the problem wasn't POST but the starting function for retrieving obj array. Just changed in:

```
var obj=$('#tablePtf td:nth-child(1)').text();
```

and now works as aspected.

Comment: you were saying.. *"The 'obj' array is not empty (tested)"*..?

Comment: Yes, i tested with 'alert(obj)' in error function and it returned the set of items. I am not sure because I'm newbie but the 'map' method seemed to return a single string with items separated by commas. Maybe it needs splitting, but I was luck and found the solution. Thanks for your attention.